# Magick++ makefile doesn't work but seemingly same command line option works

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, imagemagick

I have been using makefiles to compile programs, and I have just started using the image magick library and I am clearly doing something wrong.

The line I added was: `Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs`

Here is my makefile, on running make I am informed that the (linker?) cannot find Magick++.h

```
CFLAGS = -g -fPIC

SOURCES= $(wildcard *.cpp)

OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SOURCES))

TARGET=$(lastword $(subst /, ,$(realpath .)))

LINKS= -lcprocessing -lglut -lGLU -lGL

all: $(TARGET)
    @echo $(TARGET) built

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    @g++ $(CFLAGS) $(LINKS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) `Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs`

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)
```

However, running:

```
g++ -lcprocessing -lglut -lGLU -lGL `Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs` Spot.cpp -o Spot
```

Compiles and works fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: Exactly the same commands given in exactly identical environments yield exactly the same result (race conditions nonwithstanding). So something has to be *different*. Unfortunately we cannot really tell, because you didn't give the relevant output from the `make` run. Checking the output of `Magick++-config` in either environment might be helpful, too.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are good that the output of `Magick++-config` is different in the Makefile and on the console (because that output is what *should* give the appropriate options to the compiler, like where to find the header files).

Modify the Makefile so that it prints the output from `Magick++-config` (with the options you gave), and compare it against the output you get on the command line.

If you're looking for a quick fix, manually replace the command in the backticks with the (apparently functional) output you get on the command line.

Comment: ls /usr/include | grep "mag"

gives:    ImageMagick

`Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs`

gives:    bash: -I/usr/include/ImageMagick: No such file or directory

So this is what I get from the shell.. I don't know exactly how to modify the makefile to echo the command output, I attempted but had gotten semantical errors.

Comment: @jett: Comments aren't a good place to post output of anything. Better amend your question. I see that the output of your `Magick++-config` yields "-I/usr/include/ImageMagick", which is exactly what your compiler needs *instead* of the corresponding `Magick++-config` call in backticks in line 15 of your Makefile. But that is a kludge; to really fix the problem, you should find out why the backtick substitution in your Makefile does not yield the same output as a direct call on the command line. (While you're at it, read up on what backticks actually do, as your comment indicates you should...)

Comment: @jett: My guess at the moment is that you extended your PATH variable to include the directory with `Magick++-config` in it, but did not `export` that PATH, so your Makefile doesn't find `Magick++-config` in the first place. If that is the case, there should be an error message about it in your `make` output.